# After login sshpass how can i execute multiple commands

Tags: shell, unix

Can you please suggest how can I check the status of above customer?

```
   sshpass  -p "${Passw}" ssh -tt -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@"${Hostname}" su - servlet -c 'whoami && ServletController -log -b prod_"${Cust_name}" status -type web |grep running'
```

In the above script I can login into Hostname and can switch to servlet user but when I am trying to check the status of any customer its not giving output i.e. after switch to servlet user nothing happens?

Can anyone suggest how can this be implemented?

the output got:

```
[root@***** User]# sh -x servlet_restart.sh hostname Password Cust_name + Hostname=***** + Passw=Password + Cust_name=Tenet + shopt -s nocasematch + sshpass -p Password ssh -tt -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@****** su - servlet -c 'whoami && ServletController -log -b prod_"${Cust_name}" status -type web |grep run' servlet bash: ServletController: command not found Connection to ***** closed.
```

Comment: [root@***** User]# sh -x servlet_restart.sh hostname Password Cust_name
+ Hostname=*****
+ Passw=Password
+ Cust_name=Tenet
+ shopt -s nocasematch
+ sshpass -p Password ssh -tt -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@****** su - servlet -c 'whoami && ServletController -log -b prod_"${Cust_name}" status -type web |grep run'
servlet
bash: ServletController: command not found
Connection to ***** closed.

This is the output I am getting

Comment: The output should be in the question, formatted as code.

Comment: Where are you defining `Cust_name` to the remote shell doing the expansion? And where is `ServletController` coming from? Is it in the default PATH? In the destination user's dotfiles? If so, *which specific* dotfiles? An exported shell function? What *is* it, and why is it something the remote shell is expected to know how to do?

Comment: BTW, running `set -x` in the remote shell, as in `su - servlet -c 'set -x; whoami ...` will generally do a lot of good in terms of showing the actual commands being run.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I am passing parameter from jenkins.ServletController is an exe (we created this function)

Comment: @KeithThompson Can you explain it please. I am sorry I am not able to understand

Comment: @user3382387, it's an executable *located where*? How is it put in the PATH of the servlet user? If you replace `ServletController -log` with `/path/to/ServletController -log` (with the real path to its actual location on disk), does that fix the problem?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : Yeah it worked after I put the real path. But stuck into another ssh -tt -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@****** 'su - servlet; /*/*/*/ServletController -log status -local webBlessing; exit'
Its not working I have to manually press Ctrl+D then only it works. Any suggestion please

Comment: The `;` after the `su - servlet` means that you're waiting until the `su` command exits before you run the `ServletController` command -- which means that the effect of `su` *doesn't apply to* `ServletController`.

Comment: I would suggest switching from `su` to `sudo` (if configured to allow root to do anything), as in: `ssh -tt -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@****** 'sudo -u servlet /*/*/*/ServletController -log status -local webBlessing'`. BTW, the `/*/*/*/...` is quite inefficient as opposed to hardcoding the real path, and could also be exploited by an adversary who has access to an unprivileged account like `nobody` that can still create `/tmp/a/b/c/ServletController` with code they want to execute.

Comment: Alternately, you can generate a command that's safe for `su` with multiple rounds of escaping: `printf -v inner_cmd '%q ' /full/path/to/ServletController -log status -local webBlessing; printf -v su_cmd '%q ' su - servlet -c "$inner_cmd"; ssh root@.... "$su_cmd"`